# only work with static query, how t use it with variable

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, sh

when i use

```
FROM `201509_data_file` a
```

it's working

but i need to use it on crontab
so i need to use

> now=$(date '+%Y%m')

i have already trying to put it on [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899922/work-on-manual-query-but-not-work-at-bash-sh-file)
and the result is error

then i try to use

> mysql -h10.251.38.76 -utestuser -ptestpass -Dtestarea <
>   "/home/supertest/ripdsi.sql"

with normal statement

> FROM `201509_data_file` a
>   result : working

the problem is
how to make it works when i want to use

```
FROM `${now}_data_file` a
```

Comment: The `%` has special meaning in cron. Try `now=$(date +'%%Y%%m')`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like not to use `'` for the date formatting.

```
user@mypc ~
$ statement="select * from $(date +%Y%m)_data_file"

user@mypc ~
$ mysql -u root -prootpassword -D test -e "$statement"
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'test.201510_data_file' doesn't exist
```

Comment: how to use it all under 1 sh script ?
sample at my first post link "HERE" @James

Comment: Whether you run it on console or in script, this should work.

Comment: /RIP-TEST.sh
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''regional', 'branch', 'subBranch', 'cluster', 'user_type', 'user_id', 'name')
SE' at line 1

Comment: Please post your RIP-TEST.sh code till line number 2 will do.